# Convincing pdfbook to assume letterpaper

Tags: pdfpages, paper-size, book-design, pdfbook

I have a small booklet in half-`letterpaper` size:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[paperheight=8.5in,paperwidth=5.5in]{geometry}

\usepackage{mwe}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-13]
\end{document}
```

But when I run `pdfbook` on the resulting PDF, I invariably receive—no matter what the original page size is—a PDF that is 11.7 by 8.27 inches.  How can I use `pdfbook` (or `pdfjam`) to simply (and appropriately) mash these pages together without trying to alter the paper size?

#### Ideal

After compiling the above MWE, I have a PDF that is exactly half of the size of a sheet of letter paper.  I would like to run `pdfbook` (or a custom call to `pdfjam`) such that these pages are set two-up on the long edge in the correct configuration to bind it as a book.

---

```
$ pdfbook -p letter test.pdf out.pdf
          ----
  pdfjam: This is pdfjam version 2.08.
  pdfjam: Reading any site-wide or user-specific defaults...
          (none found)
  pdfjam ERROR: no PDF/JPG/PNG file found at -p
```

Comment: Not knowing what arguments you're using with pdfbook, it appears its default paper size is a4. Have you tried `pdfbook -p letter in.pdf out.pdf` already?

Comment: @MikeRenfro I have not, but I've edited in its output.

Comment: As far as I can tell, `pdfbook` passes `--landscape` to `pdfjam` no matter what. Since you want portrait, I am not sure `pdfbook` is a good choice. Perhaps `pdfjam` can do this if invoked directly? `pdfbook` is a fairly simple wrapper for `pdfjam` - it isn't adding any functionality of its own to speak of. `pdfjam` should be able to do it given that it is a much more powerful interface to `pdfpages`. Failing that, I guess you could use `pdfpages` itself.

Comment: @cfr I don't want portrait; I want a landscape layout of 2-up portrait pages such that the resulting PDF is exactly `letterpaper`.  I'll try to edit my question to be clearer; perhaps I'm being a bit short :)

Comment: You're right, sorry. I'm confused. However, having spent the last 10 minutes of my life with `pdfjam`, I've concluded that it is a good way to make something which works well (`pdfpages`) break horribly. I don't know quite what it is doing but the file it tries to compile appears not to be to the liking of `pdfpages` at all. I suspect that it may need a better configuration/preamble file and that it is not loading `geometry` by default even if it is available but I'm not certain.

Comment: Also it is very badly behaved. It has *no business* writing to `/var/tmp`. These are not files which should persist between reboots! It should be using `/tmp`.

Comment: Here is the line it tries to use in one of my attempts (from the temporary `.tex` file): `\includepdfmerge[paper=letter=--outfile=out.pdf]{/var/tmp/pdfjam-KAsjst/source-1.pdf,-}`. That is, `pdfjam` is failing to parse options passed to it correctly. This is pretty basic stuff. I wouldn't trust it to do anything after seeing this.

Comment: On second thoughts, I'm impressed you managed to get a pdf from it at all. Certainly more than I managed.

Comment: OK. Try this. I still wouldn't let this script fetch me a jammy dodger but it does seem to work. `pdfbook --paper letter --outfile out.pdf -- in.pdf`. Note that the `--` before the input pdf is *essential*. This is not at all normal behaviour for a shell script. It is parsing options extremely weirdly. I wouldn't like to say it is dangerous but I wouldn't trust that it is not. However, as long as you don't pass it anything dangerous, it should be fine ;).

Comment: @cfr Thanks for taking a look into it! The above works; do you mind posting it as an answer, and perhaps where you found the `--paper` option?  (The manpage leaves a bit to be desired…)

Comment: @SeanAllred Done! (At possibly immoderate length...)

Comment: There is an alternative `pdfbook` program available at: http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/support/pdfbook. You might be interested to have a look at that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The basic problem here is that `pdfjam` exhibits non-standard behaviour and is rather poorly documented. Since `pdfbook` is basically a minimal wrapper for `pdfjam`, it inherits these deficiencies while further obscuring the source of problems.

In this case, you can workaround the problem using

```
pdfbook --paper letter --outfile out.pdf -- in.pdf
```

Note that the `--` before the input pdf is essential. This is not at all normal behaviour for a shell script. `pdfjam` is parsing options extremely weirdly. I wouldn't like to say it is dangerous but I wouldn't trust that it is not. However, as long as you don't pass it anything dangerous, it should (hopefully) be reasonably safe.

Figuring this out takes a little detective work. The manual pages for `pdfbook` and `pdfjam` are not terribly informative. Essentially, I started by reading the script `pdfbook` which shows how it invokes `pdfjam`. This is relatively straightforward. I then switched to testing `pdfjam` directly to try to narrow down the problem.

```
pdfjam --help
```

is the most useful source of documentation I found. Part of this includes the following:

```
Usage: pdfjam [OPTIONS] [--] [FILE1 [SEL1]] [FILE2 [SEL2]]...
```

and

```
 --paper PAPERSPEC  (or simply --PAPERSPEC)
              Specify a LaTeX paper size, for example
              '--paper a4paper' or simply '--a4paper' for ISO A4 paper.
              If the LaTeX 'geometry' package is installed, a wider range
              of paper sizes is available.  For details see documentation
              for LaTeX and/or the 'geometry' package.
              [Default for you at this site: paper=a4paper]
 --papersize '{WIDTH,HEIGHT}'
              Specify a custom paper size, e.g.,
                  --papersize '{10in,18cm}'
              (Note the braces, and the comma!)
              If the 'geometry' package is not found, this has no effect.
```

and

```
* '--' can be used to signal that there are no more options to come.
```

What this does not tell you is that the script is parsing options non-standardly and that ***-- is essential*** if certain options are passed. Normally, you only need `--` if one of the main arguments passed to a shell script might otherwise be mistaken for an option (e.g. a filename begins with `-`) or if you wish to prevent misuse (e.g. when a shell is invoked). In the case of `pdfjam`, though, if you write

```
pdfjam --paper letter --outfile out.pdf in.pdf
```

you will get errors. Debugging with `--no-try` shows that the script is passing something like `paper letter--outfile` as an optional argument when invoking the PDF merge command offered by `pdfpages`. It then tries to merge `out.pdf` and `in.pdf`. None of which works, obviously.

Turning to `pdfjam` itself, you can see how it parses options:

```sh
for arg
do
    case $arg in
        --quiet | -q | --configpath)
            verbose=false ;
            ;;
        --version | -V)
            echo "$version"
            exit 0 ;
            ;;
        --batch)
            batch=true ;
            ;;
        --help | -u | -h)
            help=true ;
            ;;
        --vanilla)
            vanilla=true ;
            ;;
        *)
            ;;
    esac
done
```

It then parses any remaining options separately later in the file. I'm not entirely sure why it does this but the upshot is that it is essentially unable to tell the difference between an option and an argument. If you don't tell it explicitly that the options are finished, it fails to parse any remaining options correctly. This is actually pretty bad as it is letting arbitrary stuff get passed onto `pdfpages` even when it makes no sense. Although I don't know if this could be exploited, it is the kind of thing which can make scripts vulnerable to exploitation.

Moreover, including

```
* '--' can be used to signal that there are no more options to come.
```

does not constitute proper documentation of this behaviour because this is a standard behaviour for shell scripts. What is not standard is that this is required *even if your first argument proper has a non-weird name* i.e. even if `in.pdf` has a filename which does not start with `-`.

This is buggy behaviour in my view. Shell scripts ought not behave this way. Moreover, it uses `/var/tmp` for temporary files. This is also non-standard and problematic. It ought to use `/tmp` so that the temporary files it creates are removed on reboot, for example. Although these remain around only if `--no-tidy` is passed, the behaviour is still unexpected and, I think, undesirable for a script of this kind.

So I would be careful in using `pdfjam` and wrappers such as `pdfbook`. For example, I would avoid piping the output of other processes to `pdfjam` and only invoke the script or its wrappers manually.